# Why is this Python attribute error happening in my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is my Python file (`myfile.py`). I am new to Python and programming.

```
title = "The meaning of life" #myfile.py
```

And it's present in 'learning_python' directory.

[image: This is the error which I get.]

Comment: Can't reproduce. Make sure you only have one `myfile.py` laying around, and it's present in your current working directory.

Comment: Is the code shown the complete file?

Comment: Can you paste myfiles.py here?

Comment: Can you make a `cat myfile.py` and verify that the content ist the expected one?

Comment: Please post the actual file here. You should also copy and paste error messages instead of a screenshot.

Comment: use `print(myfile.__file__)` to see full path to file which you import. Maybe you import different file with name `myfile.py`. And later use this path to open file in any editor and see if you have `title` in this file.

Comment: That's the complete file. And it's present in working directory.

Comment: Along with what @furas suggests you check, what *is* in the module `myfile` that you do import? Check with `dir(myfile)`.

Comment: Building on @furas try `with open(myfile.__file__,'r') as f:` `for x in f:` `print(x)` to see the full contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from myfile import *
```

you should then be able to access the variable by it's name. (in your case, `title`)